# How to use shared views but have buttons appear in one side but not the other?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, razor, model-view-controller

So I have a view created and completed.
But I am going to create another view that is very similar (infact actually uses the same screen) but there are some difference. You can see it as a "Administration" screen where crud functionalities are present such as Creating a new item in the record for my database, editing or deleting records.

Is there a way where Certain buttons or html tags can appear in one area but not in another? In the current "shared" screen, I use datatables to display the table as well as using stringBuilder to build the html tags in my .cs file. 
But how I created the button such as edit and delete was using the  tag. How this is being called is through javascript function and an ajax call calling my method that generates the html tags in an string builder.

```
var htmlTable = new StringBuilder();
htmlTable.Append{<table><Tr><td><img src='/images/Edit.png'>...
```

I also have separate button that is not an inline tag in the html builder.

```
<input type="button" id="btnAddRecipeLink" value="New Link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

Also in my _layout.cshtml file i also have the link used to click onto to view the "admin section"

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li>
     @Html.ActionLink("Recipe Management", "Index", "Recipe")
</li>
</ul>
```

Where the "Index" is the name of the already completed view in my Recipe Folder in the Views folder.

If this isn't really possible or doesn't makes sense, would the best and logical approach is to have another Controller and Model created for the "Administration" section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our application when we want to use the same view for different purposes we control the elements that are different in the sharedview by some property in the ViewModel of that page.

For example we have a property IsAdministrator in the ViewModel and in case of Admin it is set to true and in the razor view we go like:

```
@{
if(Model.IsAdministrator)
{
   @: <a href='edit'>Admin can edit</a>
}
else
{
   @: <span>You are not an admin!</span>
}
}
```

So we just set this property in the same controller action or some processor method based on the rules...